# C++: Generic base member functions with specific types in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

As will soon become apparent, I'm still learning C++.
For the problem I'm working on, I have a class which has a std::map data member and a number of member functions which operate on the map. I'm going to need some instances for which the map is sorted ascending and some for which the map is sorted descending. The code of the member functions will be identical for both cases (except for type issues--as I've learned, changing the Compare function for a map changes its type). I'm struggling to make this work without having to rewrite the functions for each case.

Here's some toy code which I hope illustrates my situation (inlining functions just for compactness):

```
class MyClass {
public:
    map<int, int>::iterator get_top(){ return data.begin(); }
    int sum_elements(){ 
        int sum = 0;
        for ( map<int,int>::iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it){
            sum += it->second;
        }
    }
};
```

Ideally I would have a base class which defines the functions and two derived classes which define the data member, one for ascending and one for descending:

```
class Ascending : public MyClass {
private:
    std::map<int, int, std::less<int> > data;
};
class Descending : public MyClass {
private:
    std::map<int, int, std::greater<int> > data;
};
```

But of course this doesn't work because the base class needs to have the data member defined in order to operate on it. 
The "easy" way out would be to have two standalone classes and copy/paste the member functions into both. But that would be wasteful, and I feel in my heart that C++ must have an elegant solution to my problem.

Comment: You could just define the functions as free functions. This will save you from redundant inheritance.

Comment: You could define a template class instead and pass the actual map type...

Comment: @40two wouldn't I have to make the data member public to pass it to a free function in user code?

Comment: @Deduplicator template class sounds like a good solution. I'm a little intimidated by the added syntax overhead, but definitely reading up on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a functor that overloads `operator()(int, int)` (the comparison), and that takes as a constructor the order in which you want to sort the elements. This way, you can define the map 
as `std::map<int, int, SortCriterion> data(comp)`, where `comp` is defined as `SortCriterion comp(true)` for example for ascending order, and `SortCriterion comp(false)` for descending. This way, both maps will have the same type, `map<int, int, SortingCriterion>`.

Code below:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class SortCriterion
{
    bool ascending;
public:
    SortCriterion(bool sorting_type): ascending(sorting_type){};
    bool operator()(int x, int y) const
    // if not marked const, 
    // clang++ spits a compile-time error on insert
    // however g++ compiles it ok
    {
        if(ascending) // ascending
            return x<y;
        else
            return x>y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Both maps below have the SAME type, map<int, int, SortCriterion>
    map<int, int, SortCriterion> m1(SortCriterion(true)); // ascending
    map<int, int, SortCriterion> m2(SortCriterion(false)); // descending


    m1.insert({1,1});
    m1.insert({2,2});

    m2.insert({1,1});
    m2.insert({2,2});

    cout << "First map:" << endl;
    for(auto elem: m1)
        cout << "[" << elem.first << "," << elem.second\
             << "]" << endl;

    cout << endl << "Second map:" << endl;
    for(auto elem: m2)
        cout << "[" << elem.first << "," << elem.second\
             << "]" << endl;
}
```

Comment: @MattAdams, you are welcome. This is a fairly standard technique in STL, using functors with state to specify comparison predicates (this allows you to overcome exactly the type of problem you had, namely keeping the same type for the container).